# Four of a kind combinatorics, why is my logic incorrect?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification

I'm going through a probability textbook and getting stuck on a simple question. From a standard deck of 52 cards, what is the probability of getting a 4 of a kind?

I've seen many of the answers, and I understand how to get there. The straightforward way of answering the question is just to realize there's $ 13$ four of a kinds with $48$ choices for the 5th card so the solution is just $$ \frac {13 *48} {52 \choose 5} = \frac {624} {52 \choose 5}$$

I understand how to get to this answer. My question is, **why is the following approach incorrect?**

For the first card we can draw any of the 52 cards, we must draw the remaining cards with the same rank. This equates to :

$$52 * 3 * 2 * 1$$

Then for the 5th card we have 48 remaining cards so we have:

$$52*3*2*1 * 48$$

Now, furthermore, these 5 cards can be arranged in any manner. So for the total number of ways we have:

$$ \frac {52 *3 *2 *1 * 48} {5!} $$

Then we simply divide by ${52 \choose 5}$ to get our final probability.

Now it turns out this answer is wrong, but I cannot figure out why?

The mistake is obviously in this step:

$$ \frac {52 *3 *2 *1 * 48} {5!} $$

But for the life of me I cannot figure out why. It seems the correct answer is to divide by $4!$ factorial instead of $5! $, but why? We have 5 cards, they can be arranged in $5!$ ways

Comment: Presumably, you mean four of a kind when drawing a standard five-card poker hand?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Hi Thomas, yes that is correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You say "*for the* **first** *card*."  Such lines of thinking are dangerous if you are mixing both *order matters* and *order doesn't matter* in the same calculation.  For instance, with order mattering, where did you account for the possibility of the first card being the "kicker" (*the card not a part of the quadruple*)?

So, for order mattering, pick the slot that the kicker could appear in, then pick what it was.  Now, from left to right in the remaining slots pick the first card in the quadruple, then pick the others in the quadruple giving a total of $5\cdot 52\cdot 48\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1$ such hands with order mattering.  Dividing by $5!$ gives the number of such hands if order doesn't matter.  It wasn't that dividing by $5!$ was wrong and $4!$ was correct, it was that you were missing a factor in the numerator corresponding to where the kicker was.

Comment: Ah I think I understand. The kicker can be in 5 slots, my solution only represents 1 of those 5 slots, so I'm off by 1/5th. I think I understand, though now I think to the next question which is a full house and I'm a bit more nervous. If I can ask a follow question. You're saying that I'm mixing where order matters and doesn't matter, could you point out where I'm supposing order matters and where it doesn't? I think that's one of the areas of my confusion.

Comment: You just need that whether order matters-or not- to be the same in the numerator and denominator.   We favour obtaining  1 from 13 kinds (in all suits of that kind) and 1 from 48 remaining cards, when selecting 5 from 52 cards in *no particular arrangement*. The probability for this is:$$\dfrac{\dbinom{13}1\dbinom{48}1}{\dbinom{52}5}$$

Comment: @Jackson by having thought in terms of "first card of the quadruple" and "second card of the quadruple" you were using "order matters".  These "first" and "second" concepts do not exist if you are looking at your hand where order doesn't matter, with the ability to freely mix those cards without changing the hand itself.  Better to think of "*these cards collectively make up the quadruple (in no particular order)*" using binomial coefficients where possible.  Otherwise, you could forgo binomial coefficients entirely so long as you do so for the denominator as well.

Comment: You correctly divided out by $5!$ in order to account for this, but again... the fewer times you need to (for lack of better description) '*transition*" your calculations in your answer from one style to another the better since doing so gives more opportunity for errors and confusion.

Comment: @JMoravitz thank you so very much! Combinatorics and permutations have always thrown me for a loop, it seems I always forget to account for one thing or another. Trying to do the problem multiple ways seems to help my understanding, and folks like you are a godsend. I really appreciate you taking the time. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you proceed by counting, you must be quite clear for yourself what set (of possibilities) you are counting, and then ensure that you are counting exactly that set, with no elements left out and no elements counted more than once. Here what matters ultimately is a subset of the set of $\binom{52}5$ hands of $5$ cards, but for a probability question you can also consider the corresponding subset of the set of $52\times51\times\cdots\times 48=\frac{52!}{47!}$ possible ways of successively dealing $5$ distinct cards; this number is $5!$ times larger than the number of hands because on order among the dealt cards is recorded, but the subset will be larger by the same factor than the subset of hands, so the quotient (the probability) will be the same. Since you are dividing at the end by $5!$ to get then number of unordered hands, it is clear that you are counting ways to deal $5$ cards, and in particular the subset of these that result in a hand that is valid as $4$ of a kind.

But given that you are taking order into account, you must count all possible ways in which such a hand can be dealt, and you cannot assume that the first card dealt will be in the group of $4$. In general for counting poker hands in the way, it seems best to separately list the possible groupings among the dealt cards, and then for each count the ways to fill it in. Here the card with a unique rank can be in each of the $5$ positions, giving $5$ distinct groupings. Once this grouping is fixed you can fix the cards in the $5$ positions in any order; choosing those in the other positions first one has $52\times3\times2\times1\times48$ valid possibilities as you correctly computed. But you get the same number for each of the $5$ patterns, so in all $5\times52\times3\times2\times1\times48$ ways to deal a four-of-a-kind. THe probability then is
$$
\frac{5\times52\times3\times2\times1\times48}{52\times51\times50\times49\times 48} 
= \frac{5\times3\times2\times1}{51\times50\times49}
= \frac{13\times48}{\binom{52}5}
$$
in accordance with what is found by the other (easier) method.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I think I have a better understanding. Unfortunately, I tried applying my logic to another variant of the question (ways to draw 2 pair) and I'm overcounting by a factor of 2. I just wish there was some more rigorous, foolproof way of counting. I understand there are easier ways to approach these problems, but I feel frustrated that I can't do it the "long way". I think I'm leaving some understanding on the table

Comment: @Jackson for the two-pair example, be careful that you aren't talking about the "*first*" pair and the "*second*" pair.  Again, such concepts of "first" and "second" are dangerous.  You just happen to have two ranks (*card "numbers"*) used for the pairs *in no particular order*.  When picking those ranks used for pairs, pick them simultaneously with order not mattering.  $\dfrac{\binom{13}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{2}44}{\binom{52}{5}}$.  By accidentally denoting one of the pairs as the "first" versus the "second" its no wonder your answer was off by a factor of 2.

Comment: @Jackson a trick with nuance you can use is that *after* having decided which ranks were used then we can unambiguously refer to the "smaller" of the ranks and decide the suits used for it and so on... or if we were choosing people after having chosen we could start further specifying things about them by going through the selected people in order of age (*or height or name etc...*) in an unambiguous fashion.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you for the explanation the two pair. I racked my brain on that for quite a while. It was frustrating because the issue didn't show up with the full house so I approached it the same way and got stumped. With your help and practice problems, I've gotten good at doing problems the "correct" way. But I still like trying the problems by enumerating all possibilities (with duplicates etc) and then whittling it down, I feel like it helps me build intuition in a weird way. But it might be more pain that it's worth.

Comment: Your second comment is also really helpful. It seems like maybe the better approach is to separate "characterstics" and apply combinations to those and then multiply. So in the case of cards, calculate the different ways you can choose the rank. Then calculate the different suits those 2 ranks can have. Rank and suit being the two different characteristics? Of course these things get multiplied so the "order" doesn't matter, you could do 4C2 * 4C2 to represent suits then 13C2 for the rank. Do I have that right?

Answer (score 0):

By dividing by $5!$, remember that you are grouping sets of $120$ arrangements and treating them as $1$. In other words, you are considering $119$ combinations redundant.

Imagine (2 of spades, 2 of diamonds, 2 of hearts, 2 of clubs, Ace of Hearts). You are saying that there are $120$ rearrangements of this which you have counted that are considered the same. Let's take (2 of hearts, 2 of spades, 2 of diamonds, 2 of clubs, A of Hearts). This checks out since what you are saying is essentially - for each card, pick up all the cards in its rank, and then pick any other card. However, let's try this. (A of Hearts, 2 of clubs, 2 of diamonds, 2 of spades, 2 of hearts). This doesn't work. You are rendering this combination redundant yet you haven't counted it in your numerator.